# Error while trying to read csv file from amazon S3 bucket

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to read the csv file from S3 bucket in AWS.

Unfortunately , the code i am using below throws an error

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
>   quote,  :    no lines available in input

Below is the code, I am trying to use for reading the csv file

```
library(aws.s3)

Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "Key A","AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "Key B")

D <-get_object("s3://dataset/Data.csv")

obj <- rawToChar(D)

con <- textConnection(obj)
claim<- read.csv2(con)
```

I am new to AWS and would be helpful if anyone could support.

Comment: Did the error message not giving you any reference? Problem is on the read.csv2 complaining the input is empty. Nothing to do with S3.

Comment: @Kannaiyan i rectified it and its working now